# Why does this google sheets function need the & symbol?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I know that this function works, but I'm trying to understand the rules behind google sheets.

Why does this function only work when I use the & symbol?

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E, ">" & AE7, E:E, "<" & AF7)
```

I'm trying to find all the numbers in column E that are bigger than AE7 (0) and smaller than AF7(15,000)

Comment: & is the concatenation operator